# Router port forwarding is unsuccessful (can add them, but they don't seem to open)

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

I have a CH6643E which I'm trying to port forward. I've always had this issue on this router, and I've ran out of ideas on how to fix it. I've searched how to port forward this specific router, and the tutorials follow the same procedure as me.

The UI is pretty straight-forward, here's a screenshot of the port forwarding page:

[image]

As you see, those three ports are supposedly open. And yes, I'm sure the local IP of my machine is 72:

[image]

**EDIT:** Also, to clear things up, my machine's local IP is static (I associated it's MAC address with the IP), but my WAN IP is dynamic.

Despite the fact I can add the port, it seems to never actually open, as suggested by every port tester I've tried. Here's an example:

[image]

I've tried opening ports utilizing software that makes use of UPnP, using port triggering instead, I've had to factory reset my router twice with failed attempts of setting up a static IP, and tinkered with a bunch of the router's settings.

Is there an obvious thing I'm missing here? How can I approach this?

Thanks in advance for the help! I'll be glad to provide any more information if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, you censored your public IP address. What’s your ISP? What are the first two blocks of your public IP address? You may not have a _public_ IP address and your ISP may be using [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

Comment: What software on your computer is waiting for connections on that port?

Comment: @DanielB Sorry about that, I heard you're not supposed to share it so freely due to safety reasons. The first blocks are 84.90, the ISP is nowo.

Comment: @user1686 It's a dedicated server for a game called Stormworks.

Comment: And is the server _running_ when you're using these "port testers"?

Comment: Your game is most likely using UDP. UDP is a connectionless protocol. The port tester will most likely not receive a response for what the game might consider malformed data.

Comment: @DanielB That could be the reason, however I also have a separate software that listens to said port, and it also comes up negative. Also, my friends cannot connect to me either way.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to know that port forwarding works only with static ip address.

If you failed to set up ip address in static mode your forwarding will never work and you need to be sure to set the proper transport protocol related to the port.

You need to check if the protocol is TCP/UDP/BOTH and set the static ip, to do that you can follow many guides on youtube:
here an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qA73fxyX9Nw.

After you fix this things, your set up in the first picture will be correct.

Comment: Port forwarding will of course also work with dynamic IP addresses. It’s just that the address may change so the rule no longer fits. But it will work.

Comment: If you want to keep dynamic ip address use port triggering instead.

Comment: Port triggering is something else entirely.

Comment: my bad then sorry

Comment: Well, port triggering is close... but it only works when there is something that can 'trigger' it. It won't work if OP only wants inbound connections.

Comment: @DanielB I don't know if you're referencing LAN or WAN IP, but my machine's local IP is static, but the router's WAN IP is not. I explained it in an edit in the post.